# Trouble extracting specific data from R

Tags: r, api, csv

Ive tried extensively to answer this question however I cant seem to adapt any existing solutions to my case (or am failing to understand how to do so).
Im attempting to extract data from an API call using the following code (which works)

```
##location details (works)
require(httr)

URL <- 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?'

request <- GET(URL,
           add_headers(User_key=""),
           query=list(entity_id = '260', 
                      entity_type = 'city'))
content(request)
ZomatoData <-content(request)
```

I then get the following response:

```
$restaurants[[13]]
$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant
$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$R
$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$R$res_id
[1] 16562670


$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$apikey
[1] ""

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$id
[1] "16562670"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$name
[1] "Home Thai"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$url
[1] "https://www.zomato.com/sydney/home-thai-cbd?
utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location
$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$address
[1] "Shop 1-2, 299 Sussex Street, CBD, Sydney"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$locality
[1] "CBD"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$city
[1] "Sydney"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$city_id
[1] 260

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$latitude
[1] "-33.8744859237"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$longitude
[1] "151.2044165656"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$zipcode
[1] "2000"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$country_id
[1] 14

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$location$locality_verbose
[1] "CBD, Sydney"


$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$switch_to_order_menu
[1] 0

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$cuisines
[1] "Thai, Salad"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$average_cost_for_two
[1] 60

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$price_range
[1] 3

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$currency
[1] "$"

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$offers
list()

$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$user_rating
$restaurants[[13]]$restaurant$user_rating$aggregate_rating
[1] "4.5"
```

This is all fine however I wish to extract only the user rating aggregate rating value and write this into a CSV file such that it has 2 columns, 1 being restaurant name and the other being the rating. 
Wondering if anyone can help?
Any kind and helpful response is greatly appreciated
UPDATE: here is the output for str(ZomatoData)

```
> str(ZomatoData)
List of 4
$ results_found: int 16056
$ results_start: int 0
$ results_shown: int 20
$ restaurants  :List of 20
 ..$ :List of 1
.. ..$ restaurant:List of 23
.. .. ..$ R                   :List of 1
.. .. .. ..$ res_id: int 16564875
.. .. ..$ apikey              : chr "api-key"
.. .. ..$ id                  : chr "16564875"
.. .. ..$ name                : chr "The Grounds of Alexandria Cafe"
.. .. ..$ url                 : chr "https://www.zomato.com/sydney/the-
grounds-of-alexandria-cafe-alexandria?
utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=ap"| __truncated__
.. .. ..$ location            :List of 9
.. .. .. ..$ address         : chr "Shop 7A, 2 Huntley Street, Alexandria, 
Sydney"
.. .. .. ..$ locality        : chr "The Grounds of Alexandria, Alexandria"
.. .. .. ..$ city            : chr "Sydney"
.. .. .. ..$ city_id         : int 260
.. .. .. ..$ latitude        : chr "-33.9110760390"
.. .. .. ..$ longitude       : chr "151.1936605722"
.. .. .. ..$ zipcode         : chr "2015"
.. .. .. ..$ country_id      : int 14
.. .. .. ..$ locality_verbose: chr "The Grounds of Alexandria, Alexandria, 
Sydney"
.. .. ..$ switch_to_order_menu: int 0
.. .. ..$ cuisines            : chr "Cafe, Coffee and Tea, Salad"
.. .. ..$ average_cost_for_two: int 80
.. .. ..$ price_range         : int 3
.. .. ..$ currency            : chr "$"
.. .. ..$ offers              : list()
.. .. ..$ thumb               : chr 

.. .. ..$ user_rating         :List of 4
.. .. .. ..$ aggregate_rating: chr "4.6"
.. .. .. ..$ rating_text     : chr "Excellent"
.. .. .. ..$ rating_color    : chr "3F7E00"
.. .. .. ..$ votes           : chr "3162"
```

Comment: Update, i've tried things like write.csv and it gives me the error: 
> write.csv(ZomatoData,"c:/Users/sanaz/Desktop/Zomato.csv")
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 
which is understandable as what im trying to write would not fit in a rectangular spreadsheet. This is why im stuck.

Comment: what do you get when you do `length(ZomatoData$restaurants)`

Comment: @Hardikgupta i get `[1] 20`

Comment: `ZomatoData$restaurants$restaurant$name`, what does this return to you?

Comment: @Hardikgupta it returns `> ZomatoData$restaurants$restaurant$name
NULL`

Comment: try `ZomatoData$restaurants$restaurant`, please post what it returns to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your sample code above, and you don't give a minimal example dataset, so I don't have the means to test this on your data.

That aside, can you try the following:

```
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,
    lapply(ZomatoData$restaurants, function(x) {
        c(x$restaurant$name, x$restaurant$user_rating$aggregate_rating) } ) );
write.csv(df, file = "summary.csv");
```

Here `restaurants` should be a list with the structure you give.

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers, ive tried your suggestion however I get this error: 
Error in do.call(rbind.data, frame, lapply(restaurants, function(x) { : 
  second argument must be a list
Am I trying it wrong?

Comment: As I said in my post, unfortunately you don't give a minimal dataset. Can you update your question to include the output of `str(ZomatoData)`? Or better still, include a minimal dataset.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @Maurits, ive put in the output of str(ZomatoData) as youve requested and yes im so sorry that the code is not reproducible due to the limitation of the Api Key. If there is no other solution to this, I will play around with the coding youve suggested and hope it will give me something. Thanks again!

Comment: If this still doesn't work, best to save `ZomatoData` in an `RData` file, and make it available (e.g. through Dropbox, Google Drive or similar). Answer should be very straightforward in that case...

Comment: ive resulted to extracting the names and ratings seperately then i will attempt to write these into a csv file as such: `data <- content(request) Name<- data$restaurants[[1]]$restaurant$name` however how would i loop this such that it returns the restaurant name for [1] and then [2] and then [3] so that i can compile them into a column in excel? I am using the  `for (i in item)` function however this is returning the error `Error in print(i) : object 'i' not found`

Comment: There's not need for a `for` loop. That's the whole purpose of the `lapply`. It's only a matter of navigating the nested list structure of `ZomatoData`. Again, please provide either some reduced sample data, or a link to an `RData` file containing `ZomatoData`.

Comment: OH Maurits! it worked! seems like something was wrong with my environment! thank you greatly!